# Rails: how to redirect in controller action with nested attributes form

Tags: ruby-on-rails, nested-forms

I am trying to redirect after a nested form has been submitted.

I have two resources: `products` and `productvariants`, where a `product` has_many `productvariants`. On my `ProductsController.rb` I have an `add_sku` action:

```
class Admin::ProductsController < ApplicationController

def add_sku
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @product.productvariants.build
  @page_title = 'Create new productvariant'
end
```

And a relative form of:

```
<%= form_for [:admin, @product], :html => {'role' => 'form' } do |f| %>
  <%= f.fields_for :productvariants, Productvariant.new do |ff| %>
    <div">
      <%= ff.label :hero_id %>
      <%= ff.select(:hero_id, Image.joins(:albums => :section).where(:sections => {:title => 'shop'}).order('file_name asc').map{|s| [s.file_name, s.id]}, {}, {}) %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= ff.label "Variant title" %>
      <%= ff.text_field :title %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= ff.label :price %>
      <%= ff.text_field :price %>
    </div>
    <div>
      <%= ff.label :stock %>
      <%= ff.text_field :stock %>
    </div>
  <% end %>
  <div class="actions create">
    <%= f.submit "Save" %>
  </div>
<% end %>
```

I would like to find out how I would redirect to the show page of `productvariants` after I hit submit. Something similar to this:

```
class Admin::ProductsController < ApplicationController

def add_sku
  @product = Product.find(params[:id])
  @product.productvariants.build
  @page_title = 'Create new productvariant'
  ? if @product.productvariants.save
  ?   flash[:notice] = "The productvariant has been successfully added to the product."
  ?   redirect_to :controller => :productvariants, :action => :show, :id => @productvariant
  ? else
  ?   render :action => :add_sku
  ? end
end
```

How could I implement this?

Thank you in advance!

Comment: You are adding potentially many product variants not just one so you wouldn't want to redirect to the show action of a single variant (which one would you pick and why?) rather, you would want to redirect to a nested route for the index action for the product variants of a single product. product/1/product_variants is maybe the url you are looking for so I suggest you have a think about what you really want to do and restructure your question accordingly

Comment: That is actually odd and a mistake. I would like to add only one, but it requires `productvariants`. I suspect because the relation is `has_many`?

Comment: Then maybe your relationship is wrong. Maybe you need a product belongs_to product_variant ? then you just add a select box instead of a nested form?

Comment: I would like to have the possibility to create a productvariant of a given product from the products show page. A product can have multiple productvariants, but I want to add only one at a time, which should be associated to the product right after it's create. Currently I have to create a product variant and select its metaproduct. This works, but I would like to add something cleaner.
Right now I am able to create an associated product variant, but after the create the product show page is rendered. Which is ok, but I was wondering How I could redirect to the nested resource.

Comment: Ok, then this is a little tricky because you need grab the newly created product variant. Tricky because you can't just get the latest id for the relationship as someone else may have just done the same thing at the same time. So you need to find the product variant using the params hash (@product_variant = ProductVariant.find_by(whatever params make this record unique) then redirect to @product_variant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per my last comment on your question, you need to find the product variant that has just been created using the params hash values that make the ProductVariant record unique

```
@product_variant = ProductVariant.find_by(whatever params make this record unique)
```

then

```
redirect_to @product_variant
```

Comment: thank you very much. I had no time to try it and confirm, because in the process I stumbled on something else which I have to solve before this. Maybe you can take a look at my rather long question here:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59881842/how-to-have-a-nested-form-with-two-separate-scoped-selects-of-the-same-resource Thanks in advance!!!